# Cleared CMOS and now Windows won't load

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, windows-11, computer-building

I just built a new PC with the following parts.

- [Intel Core i9-13900KF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BCFM3CJ4)
- [MSI Gaming Radeon RX 6800](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BDGJLQP5)
- [ASUS ROG Strix B760-F](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BR8W84MB)
- [G.SKILL Trident Z5 DDR5 RAM 64GB (2x32GB)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BJ7X9P1W)
- [SAMSUNG 870 QVO SATA III SSD 8TB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089C3TZL9)

When I built it, it was working just fine running Windows 11 Pro. This morning, I was playing with some of the BIOS settings and I must have accidently enabled "Chassis Intrusion Detection" because when I tried booting back in, I got a message saying "The computer case is open. Please make sure..." whatever. I looked it up and it said to fix this, I needed to remove the CMOS battery. I did that, waited 5 minutes before putting it back in and now it wont load windows. I end up getting a blue screen:

[image]

> INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE

I'm then brought to an advanced options page, but none of the options there fix the issue.

Startup Repair just ends right away saying it couldn't repair my PC. System Restore says I need to specify which Windows installation to restore, but doesn't help me beyond that. And System Image Recovery says an error occurred and gives me a code (0x80070002).

When I go into BIOS, I am able to see my SSD as one of the bootable options and the boot menu looks right, but it just keeps giving me the same issue.

I then tried to just do a clean install using the same USB I used the first time, but when I do, the Windows installer can't seem to find my SSD.

I tried opening the command prompt from the advanced options page and oddly, it is showing my drive as 'X' instead of 'C'. I don't know if that is part of the issue.

I then tried removing the new SSD and added an old Toshiba MK5076GSX 500GB HHD to run a clean install on it, but again, it wasn't finding the HHD either despite it showing up in BIOS. This tells me it's probably not the SSD that is the issue.

I tried plugging the SSD into my other PC using a USB adapter and all the files look to be correct, but I honestly don't know what to even look for.

I'm now at a loss and have no idea where to go from here. If I were to replace something, I wouldn't even know what to replace since it all seems to be working on it's own, but it's just not working together. Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here are my SATA settings, but I'm not sure what they should be.
[image]

Comment: Maybe the SATA mode changed (got reverted)?

Comment: @TomYan What would I need to look for to check that?

Comment: Well, get into the BIOS/UEFI settings and find the option? (But if you are unaware of the option, then it's kinda unlikely that you have changed it before you install Windows and now it got reverted to some default...unless someone else "built" the PC for you.)

Comment: Hmm, kinda strange that there seems to be no mode setting option for it. Can you add the exact model of your motherboard?

Comment: I added the PCH settings to the post. I built it myself, but I don't really know what I'm doing. As for changes I made before removing the CMOS battery, those were all reset to default setting.

Comment: @TomYan Oh. I thought I had the motherboard info up there. It is ASUS ROG Strix B760-F

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149558/discussion-between-tomakpo-and-tom-yan).

Comment: Windows 11 requires Secure Boot verify that CPM is disabled and Secure Boot is enabled.

Comment: @Windows 11 only requires Secure Boot at Windows Setup. Having it disabled does not break booting. (You can even bypass the requirement by installing with dism and bcdboot.) (Well, not sure about the case in which BitLocker and/or TPM is involved though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TomYan helped me figure this out. It looks like at some point, "Enable VMD controller" was set to Enabled. When I disabled it, the issue was fixed right away.